# how to provide specific wifi credentials when application is launched in ios?

Tags: ios, reachability

how I can start a system service for example wifi, when an application is launched on ios? my application just run in one specific wifi connection only.......
 i am using Reachability and also cheched wifi connections but i want to provide specific custom  wifi credentials.

```
Reachability* wifiReach = [Reachability reachabilityForLocalWiFi];
NetworkStatus netStatus = [wifiReach currentReachabilityStatus];
if (netStatus!=ReachableViaWiFi){

   UIAlertView *alertView = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:NSLocalizedString(@"No WIFI available!", @"AlertView") message:NSLocalizedString(@"You have no wifi connection available. Please connect to a WIFI network.", @"AlertView")delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:nil otherButtonTitles:@"Ok", nil];
    [alertView show];
}else{

    printf("\n wifi");

}
```

Answer (score 2):

It's not possible to establish a WiFi connection from within your app (at least not without using private APIs or a jailbroken device). It can only be configured by the user from the iOS Settings.

If you're developing an Enterprise app usually devices can have their WiFi pre-configured either by using [Apple Configurator](https://itunes.apple.com/ca/app/apple-configurator/id434433123?mt=12) or a [MDM](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mobile_device_management) (Mobile Device Management) software.

Comment: My Application related to yhis type of application....       https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/in-flight-entertainment-by/id563516237?mt=8

Comment: Then you will need to provide instructions on the screen on how to connect to the appropriate Wi Fi network if you are unable to reach your server

Comment: how to provide instructions on the screen ? how to provide local wifi credentials ?